# Circle Home causing weird IP and port forwarding issues

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, remote-desktop, port-forwarding

I am currently living in my parents' house where they have an internet control device called Circle Home. I am trying to set up port forwarding on the router so that I can use Windows RDP when off of my home network. I have set up everything correctly as far as I can tell, but I'm still having issues. When setting a target IP for the port to forward to, I put in the (static) IP for my PC. However, that didn't work, and on further inspection, I discovered that the IP address of my computer, as opposed to the 192.168.1.xxx address that I set, was actually 107.15.168.xxx. Even stranger, when looking up the IP of my other devices, I saw that they had the *exact same* address as my PC. I know that this is a big no-no in the networking process, so I'm confused as to 1. why it would appear this way and 2. why the network is able to function without getting shared IP errors. How can I get the port to forward correctly through Circle and to my PC? (And no, removing the device isn't an option, my parents basically worship its controlling capabilities)

Comment: How are you checking the IP address of your devices?

Answer (score 0):

Circle uses a method of spoofing (packet interception) called ARP poisoning. Without going into too much detail on what ARP is responsible for, Circle essentially puts itself in "front of" the router. Any traffic sent to the router would first be poisoned by the Circle device. This can lead to some interesting behavior and conflicts, including MAC and IP address confusion. If you would be willing to add some screenshots I could possibly help you further, but if you just need some next steps (which is all I can give with the limited information presented) then try these on your computer:

```
ARP -a

ipconfig /all (ifconfig -a in linux)
```

Check adapter settings for abnormalities in the setup.

As for your IP address being 107.15.168.xxx rather than 192.168.1.xxx, this is simple. 107.15.168.xxx is your WAN address, this is the address you would use to connect to your network externally. Outside devices would connect to your WAN, which goes to your router/modem/combo depending on your ISP setup and is then routed to your LAN (internal ip) which would be a phone, or computer. Without further information I cannot *fix* the problem for you, but this should help explain.